# Add a list to a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, monoids

How can I add a list to a list of lists? Say I want to add `itemz` to `bagList`, which is a list of lists. How can I do that?

```
bagList itemz = mappend bagList itemz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider adding it at the front, this is faster:

```
bagItem bag item = item : bag
```

Also it looks like you're coming from an imperative mindset, the way you use `bagList` before and after the `=` is not quite right: the expressions before and after the `=` do not really represent the same construction. Before the `=` `bagItem` is used as a function, after the `=` it's used as some `Monoid` (which if `itemz` is a list would also need to be a list).

If you really do want to append the item (this will be slower, because the operation will require going all the way through the list to add the new item at the end, and the whole list will need to be reconstructed) you can do what Christoph suggests or you can go for a recursive formulation something like this:

```
appendItem :: a -> [a] -> [a]
appendItem i (x:xs) = x : appendItem i xs
appendItem i [] = i : []
```

If you both want to append and are also worried about performance, you should have a look at difference lists, for example look for the section on difference lists in [this chapter in Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more).

---

**Update**

From the comments it seems what you are actually looking for is `Map`s. We can make a `Map` with each item as a key, and the number of occurrences as the value. In your case it seems this will be a `Map String Int`.

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.Map as M

bag :: M.Map String Int
bag = M.empty

addToBag :: M.Map String Int -> [String] -> M.Map String Int
addToBag = foldl' go
  where go m i = M.insertWith (+) i 1 m

main = print $ addToBag bag ["a","b","c","a"]
-- fromList [("a",2), ("b", 1), ("c", 1)]
```

Comment: Got It. Thanks so much for your detailed explanation up there. So basically, if I want to create a data structure to store the items in a bag, and their number, can I create something like:                                                            bag :: Eq a => [a]->[a]->[a]

Comment: bag :: Eq a => [a]->[a]-[a]                                                                                      bag items nr = if null items || null nr                                                                then append bagItems []                                                                               else append bagItems items                                                                               append bagItemsNr nr ?                                                                      Can I do something like that for storing the elemesnt and numbers of items in each bg

Comment: @user9515: This is starting to sound like a separate question. I would probably not store the number of items in each set separately because you run the risk of the numbers somehow running out of sync with the item sets. After all, it is also very easy to retrieve the number of items in each sublist: `map length bag`. If you really do want to store the number with each set of items, I would probably choose a `bag :: [(Int, [a])]` where the lists of items are stored together with their length in the bag. You would then add items as such: `bagItems bag items = (length items, items) : bag`.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I have for example: ["a","b","c","c","c"] -> I want to store this list for example. Should I use something like:                                                    bag:: [(Int,[a])] and then call                                                                                  bagItems bag items = (length items, items) : bag                                           I mean I have different items in each bag? How can I store them in the most quickest way possible? Really new to this kind of programming, and it's just for curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: Until now I was thinking like                                                                                                 bag :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]                                                                                         bagItems :: bag -> [] -> [[String]]                                                                                              bagItems bag items = ([ items length ]) ....

Comment: @user9515: I'm not sure I understand what you want. If `itemz` is a list of strings, `bag` will technically be a list of lists of lists (because strings are lists as well). So I'm not sure if your example is an item in the bag or the bag itself. I also don't know what you mean with your type statement `bag :: Eq a => [Int] -> [a]` - think about it: you can't just create a list of any (Eq) type from only a list of integers as input.

Comment: @user9515: You seem to be misunderstanding some quite fundamental principles behind the Haskell type system. Maybe you should spend some more time with (for example) [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: So my question is, how can I store a list of items, for example ["a","a","b","c","c"] in a haskell programme efficiently, so for example, storing a list of items, say ["a","b","c"] then a list of the numbers of those items [2,1,2]. Can I use bags to help me solve this question? Can u put a piece of code here, regarding storing this numbers? I would appreciate it!

Comment: @user9515: Ok I think I understand what you were looking for now, although it was not so clear from the question. See my updated answer. Documentation for Data.Map is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map.html) and usage is also explained in Real World Haskell and I think Learn You A Haskell as well.

Comment: Got it now. And if I want to save more than one bag? For example, each bag has certain items, so, I don't basically add to.each bag, but I want to.save each bag to an array of bags or something like that

Comment: As with any type you can make a list of `Map`s. If you have a `[[String]]` you can use `map (addToBag bag) itemlists` to make a `[Map String Int]`. If you want you can even use another layer of `Map`s, i.e. `Map String (Map String Int)`.

Comment: bagsList :: [[M.Map String Int]]
bagsList = [[]]                                                                                                        addToBag :: M.Map String Int -> [String] -> M.Map String Int
addToBag = foldl' go
  where go m i = M.insertWith (+) i 1 m
        bagsList.append (go)
Should this be the one? Not quite sure how to append it to a list of lists, and which is the parameter. Is it go, after that where?

Comment: @user9515: I can't make sense of this amount of code in comments. If you understand the solutions I've presented (i.e. how they work) I think you have all the information you need to accomplish what you want. If you don't understand the code, take your introductory Haskell guide of choice (real world haskell or learn you a haskell) and look up the necessary concepts, I think you'll be able to figure it out. If you run into problems with your code ask a different question, this discussion is going too far off-topic from your original question.